# How to be good in Data Structures and Analysis?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, analysis, language-agnostic

I want to be good in Data Structures and Analysis esp. in Java. I often find myself very weak. What should I do to be good in it? Any good mental exercises?

Comment: PS: I've been with Data Structures and Algorithms in Java by Goodrich and Tamassia for a while. I think this book even confused me more. Looks like I'm reading a math book which has no connection to Data structures. Another book by Nell Dale & company is far better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An excellent book on complexity analysis, including the properties of popular and not-so-popular data structures, is [Introduction to Algorithms, Second Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262531968), also referred to as CLRS.  It's widely considered to be the bible of algorithms and their analysis.

For something more Java-centric, my undergraduate intro Java course used [this book](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss_b_1_13?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=data+structures+and+algorithms+in+java&x=0&y=0&sprefix=data+structur), and I found it to be adequate.

For mental exercises, you might familiarize yourself through practice.  Try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/), [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com), or google ["acm practice problem"](http://www.google.com/search?q=acm+practice+problem).  This is perhaps the thing that will give you the most tangible benefits in everyday coding.  Most all of these will accept and evaluate Java (and C/C++) solutions, so you're all set on the language front.

Comment: +1 Cormen et. al. is a really good book.  I could understand how to implement a red-black tree and had it working in a couple of evenings from reading it.

Answer (score 3):

For the analysis of the data structures, you need to study discrete mathematics (combinatorics) and statistics.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I would recommend [CLRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262531968), but since you specifically called out Java in your question, I recommend [Objects, Abstraction, Data Structures and Design: Using Java version 5.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471692646).  It has really fantastic explanations of data structures and the algorithms that make them work.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms in Java, by [R. Sedgewick](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/) is a very good book on algorithms, with java implementations.